Cannot figure out what is wrong
Okay, so I am using Netbeans and it is driving me up a wall. I managed to get a code written and it yelled at me because it wasn't in a file named after the public class. So I changed it, and now it's still not working. There is now a "command execution failed" vs the compilation error I was getting before. I have no idea what I am missing.
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ryan_Lab3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  // Added 'public' here
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            // Get the item cost from the user
            double itemCost = getPositiveDouble(scanner, "Enter the cost of the item: $");
            // Get the tax rate from the user
            double taxRate = getPositiveDouble(scanner, "Enter the tax rate (as a percentage, e.g., 7.5 for 7.5%): ");
            
            // Validate that the tax rate is not greater than 100%
            if (taxRate > 100) {
                System.out.println("Tax rate cannot exceed 100%. Setting tax rate to 100%.");
                taxRate = 100;
            }
            
            // Convert tax rate percentage to a decimal
            double taxRateDecimal = taxRate / 100.0;
            // Calculate the taxes
            double taxes = taxRateDecimal * itemCost;
            // Calculate the total cost
            double totalCost = itemCost + taxes;
            // Output the results
            printReceipt(itemCost, taxes, totalCost);
        }
    }

    // Method to get a positive double value from user input
    private static double getPositiveDouble(Scanner scanner, String prompt) {
        double value = 0.0;
        boolean validInput = false;

        while (!validInput) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            try {
                value = scanner.nextDouble();
                if (value < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
                } else {
                    validInput = true;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a numeric value.");
                scanner.next(); // Clear the invalid input
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    // Method to print the receipt
    private static void printReceipt(double itemCost, double taxes, double totalCost) {
        System.out.println("\n--- Receipt ---");
        System.out.printf("Item Cost:     $%.2f%n", itemCost);
        System.out.printf("Taxes:         $%.2f%n", taxes);
        System.out.printf("Total Cost:    $%.2f%n", totalCost);
        System.out.println("------------------");
    }
}

I tried the suggestions that pop up on the sides and none of that has worked either and I just end up putting the original code.

your application need user input, thus you should run it from the console or within netbeans terminal

You don't have a package statement in your first line. You can only omit it if your file is in the default package (src/main/java/Ryan_Lab3.java). Else you need to provide a package name.
If you file resides e.g. in (src/main/java/com/ryan/test/Ryan_Lab3.java) your first line must look like:
package com.ryan.test;


Thank you! I am no longer allowed to code when I am tired. I didn't realize I have been deleting that part until your comment. I just started over fresh and looked at what was already pre written every time you start a new project and saw it. Thank you for giving me fresh eyes even though it was something dumb
